# Redirecting communities

Tags: visualforce, community

Is there any way that I could change the communities login URL to remove **.force.com**
When I change the landing page to communities to VF page is there any way that I could change the way the user sees the url form /apex/vfpagename to /pagename?

Any help is much appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This article should point you in the right direction: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000212707&language=en_US

Comment: Thank you! that didn't answer my second question, how do I change the URL for VF pages from /apex/vfpagename?